# Plotting Line Chart and Bar Chart in flot.js for JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot

I've a JSON data like this

```
{
    "srno": 1234567890,
    "datetime": "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm",
    "meters": [
    {
        "mid": 63,
        "phase":1,
        "v": 1234,
        "c": 5678,
        "kw": 2348,
        "kwh": 2342,
        "okda" : 1,
        "poca" : 1
    },
    {
        "mid": 62,
        "phase":2,
        "v": 1234,
        "c": 5678,
        "kw": 2348,
        "kwh": 2342,
        "okda" : 1,
        "poca" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

All i want is to plot this data on my webpage. Please Help me out.
The Jquery for the same can be inferred from this link

https://jsfiddle.net/93ttkjr4/

i want this data to be populated on my web page.

Comment: what plotting library are you using?

Comment: Hi Madalin, I'm using flot.js as my plotting library

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your data into the right [format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) for Flot (which is arrays of arrays of arrays) with something like this (example_data is the JSON from your question):

```
var bar_data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < example_data.meters.length; i++){
    var meter = example_data.meters[i];
    var temp = { data: [], bars: { order: i }};
    for (item in meter){
        temp.data.push([item, meter[item]]);    
    }
    bar_data.push(temp);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93ttkjr4/1/) for a full example using the [Side-by-side Improved](https://github.com/pkoltermann/SideBySideImproved) plugin for the bars.